# How to fix Expo Android Build Gradle API Resource Failures

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo

I am trying to eject my react-native/expo application, and the android build fails in the gradle scripts.

I am using the latest version of expo (just upgraded this morning so version 32).

Every API reference is failing. Below is example output and also the portion that is failing.

This seems to be fairly common but the solutions I have seen are for older builds that appear to be implemented in the latest release. Any help is appreciated.

Gradle portion that is failing:

```
  api 'com.facebook.react:react-native:32.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-app-loader-provider:1.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-core:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-constants-interface:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-constants:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-errors:1.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-file-system-interface:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-file-system:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-image-loader-interface:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-permissions:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-permissions-interface:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-sensors-interface:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-react-native-adapter:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-task-manager:1.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-task-manager-interface:1.0.0'

  // Optional universal modules, could be removed
  // along with references in MainActivity
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-ads-admob:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-app-auth:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-analytics-segment:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-barcode-scanner-interface:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-barcode-scanner:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-camera-interface:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-camera:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-contacts:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-face-detector:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-face-detector-interface:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-font:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-gl-cpp:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-gl:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-google-sign-in:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-local-authentication:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-localization:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-location:2.0.1'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-media-library:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-print:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-sensors:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-sms:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-background-fetch:1.0.0'
```

Example Android Studio output error (same for all)

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.facebook.react:react-native:32.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

Answer (score -2):

User mistake.. I missed the eject notification that expokit failed to install.

The issue was that expokit was attempting to auto install after ejecting, but failed. To solve the issue you just have to manually install with NPM afterwords.